# Accessing helpers within the model in the controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-6.1

I am wondering why I have a helper method from a module I've mixed in with my model throwing the NoMethodError within my controller when I try to call that model's protected method. My code currently looks like this.

```
#models/my_class.rb

class MyClass
  include HelperModule
    
  def self.list_payments(payments)
     new_payments = []
     payments.each do |payment|
        payment = MyClass.new.tap do |p|
           p.quality_check = quality_check(payment)
           p.amount_with_fee = calculate_fees(payment)
        end

        if payment.valid?
          payment.save
          new_payments << payment
        end
     end
     new_payments
  end
end

 #controllers/my_classes_controller

 class MyClassController < ApplicationController
     def index
        response = Faraday.get
        unfiltered_payments = JSON.parse(response.body)["payments"]
        @payments = MyClass.list_payments(unfiltered_payments)
     end
 end
```

`quality_check` and `calculate_fees` are both within my helper module but in the controller when I call `MyClass.list_payments(payments)` I get the `NoMethodError` for both methods. I can get it to work by including the helpers within my controller and using this function as a private function within my controller, but I was trying to follow the fat model/skinny controller convention. Am I missing something here or am I okay with placing the helpers within the controller and moving this function to the controller?
using `ruby 2.6.3p62 (2019-04-16 revision 67580) [universal.x86_64-darwin20]`, and `Rails 6.1.0`

Answer (score 2):

It's because `def self.list_payments` is a *class method* but you are calling `include HelperModule` which only affects the *instance method* scope.

Quick fix, just replace `include` with `extend`.

Comment: Thanks so much Max! Sad thing is that I was just reading on this not too long ago. Looks like I need to go back and read it!

Comment: Understandable. This stuff can be a bit confusing. Only the instance methods of a module are copied over, but whether they get copied to the other class' instance or class scope depends on whether you use `extend` or `include` ...